# pdftex character protrusion without latex: what happened to protcode.tex?

Tags: pdftex, texlive, microtype, protrusion

If one uses `pdftex`, not `pdflatex`, and wants character protrusion, it used to be that one would input `protcode.tex`. That was present in texlive2015, but disappeared by texlive2019. The pdftex manual (Rev. 790) does not mention `protcode.tex`, although the `microtype` package documentation does for historical purposes. What explains its removal? Is there a substitute, or is one now expected to implement one's own decisions instead? (I do have a saved copy of `protcode.tex`.)

Comment: Indeed it seems to have been removed in 2016, see [here](http://www.tug.org/svn/pdftex/branches/stable/doc/archive/README?revision=746&view=markup), where it says that the file is unnecessary as it's been "superseded by pervasive support in distributed packages", which of course isn't quite true for plain pdftex. A version of protcode.tex is still in support/splint/extras/texmf/macros.

Comment: Thanks for that detective work!